# UrlFetchApp.fetch get stuck for authorization level 3 or returns a weird message

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

I have this code that I have found which is meant to test in order to authorize spreadsheet to export to pdf.

```
function autorizeLevel3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //this is three level authorization 
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");

  var requestData = {
    "method": "GET",
    "oAuthServiceName": "google",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"
  };

  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId()+"&fitw=true&size=A4&portrait=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenum=CENTER&exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&gridlines=false";

  // Save File to Google Drive 
  var fileName = ss.getName();
  var seplogoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData).getBlob().setName(fileName + ".pdf");
  var report = DocsList.createFile(seplogoBlob);
}
```

I have 2 problems with it:

1) when I run the script from a menu item in the spreadsheet nothing happens and the execution transcript I am getting:

```
[15-02-21 21:58:00:531 ICT] UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&fitw=true&size=A4&portrait=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenum=CENTER&exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&gridlines=false, {oAuthServiceName=google, oAuthUseToken=always, method=GET}])
```

I need to go into the embedded script and run it manually in order for it to work which is not a proper solution as others will need to use the script. Any suggestions?

2) after running it the first time where there was mostly no problem the second time (and sometimes the first) and onward I am running it I am getting the following exception:

```
Request failed for returned code 302. Truncated server response: <HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> <H1>Moved Temporarily</H1> The document has moved <A... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

I can't figure out what I was doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thx!

Comment: These two links would be helpful for you:  https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4236  and  https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4027

Comment: Thanks KRR. Authorization is not my strength but I gather that anonymous is no longer supported and I should create an application key, right? Is there a clear step by step instructions with examples that can I can use and will help me replace my issue? Thanks!

Comment: This issue is till open for me. Doesn't matter what I tried (all failed...) I always get back to the above implementation that gets stuck on the urlFetchApp. The only way I can get it to work is if I go directly into the script and run it from the script editor rather than invoking it through a menu item in the spreadsheet. Any ideas???